SSRS account doesn't connect to SQL after upgrade
I had a SQL2019 box that I upgraded to 2022.  I did the upgrade on a new box and moved the DBs over. SSRS 2019 is still on the same server it was before.
Before the upgrade SSRS was connected to the DB with the service acct.
I setup kept the same settings after the upgrade and the service acct wouldn't connect so the site wouldn't even load.
If I take the acct out of the Services group in AD it connects just fine.  So the acct has perms.
Does anyone have any idea what this could be?
I've tried a number of different perms and it always comes down to the same thing... whenever I take the acct out of the Services AD group, it logs in just fine.
